# can mySQL and MS SQL work together?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am working in a PHP website as my graduation project with a database implemented in mySQL using (phpMyAdmin). I just knew that the company I'm working my project for uses Microsoft SQL Server as they normally work ASP.NET websites to run their business.

1. Can they work together in the same Server i mean they can talk to the same database?
2. Can i use MS SQL with PHP?

Thanks

Comment: 1.) Yes 2.) Yes You will not, of course, be able to join tables across systems or anything like that, but you can connect to both and use both if need be.

Comment: yes you can use ms sql in php check here : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Comment: You can even link the mysql server in MsSql if you really want. See https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx

Comment: Yes you can, But it would be better to export and import one of them and bring them to one database. It will be more organized and easy to manage.